# Redirecting all old links from previous EE site to new WP site in one go?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I'm about to migrate from an old Expression Engine website to a new WordPress site on the same domain. Is there anything I should be aware of with respects to redirecting old links?

The old site is quite well indexed in Search engines and linked to from other sites, but because the domain name is the same, I'm unsure of how to redirect all those old links in EE to the homepage of my new WP site without having to copy-paste all the existing individual URLs in .htaccess 301 redirects.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good plugin: http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/

You can import CSV files of URLs to redirect, so use the string site:mydomain.com in Google to grab all your indexed URLs, get them into a file and when the WP site is live, import the file and then select the new target WP pages. The plugin has good 404 logging, too.